# systemd-journal + systemd-resolve + dnsmasq high cpu usage

Tags: 16.10, systemd, dnsmasq

on Ubuntu 16.10, for some minute after wifi connection, `systemd-journal`, `systemd-resolve` and `dnsmasq` tend to use almost 150% of CPU.

Is this normal?

Comment: Is it still doing it?  Can you see if it's spamming any log files?  You could see which files are recently modified in /var/log.  The manpages as suggested below will hopefully give you a better idea of what their function is, and perhaps which log files they might be writing to.

Comment: You can't use 150% of CPU. If you have a dual-core, hyper threaded CPU you are really using 37.5% of 4 CPUs even though `top` says 150% (it's an old program). If you have an i7 Quad Core with hyper-threading you are really using 18.75% of 8 CPUs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggested by another Steps of solution

Add the line `DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo` to `/etc/default/dnsmasq`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/dnsmasq
```

Restart dnsmasq via

```
sudo service systemd-resolved restart
```

Say Thanks If I helped, It went back to normal and does NOT screw around with other apps, as the previous method DID.

Cheers, Mark

Comment: Solved this problem for me on 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem in 18.04. `systemd-resolved` and `dnsmasq` tend to loop. I solved it this way:

Add or uncomment the following line in `/etc/default/dnsmasq`:

```
IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes
```

Create your own `resolv` file (`/etc/resolv.personal`) to define nameservers. You can use any nameserver here. I took two from [OpenNIC](https://www.opennic.org).

```
nameserver 5.132.191.104
nameserver 103.236.162.119
```

In `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` add or uncomment the following line:

```
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.personal
```

Then restart `dnsmasq` and disable the default resolver: `systemd-resolved`.

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

Read `man systemd-journald`; Read `man systemd-resolve`; Read `man dnsmasq`; Read `man journalctl`.

Check your log files in `/var/log/*`.

From the little you've said, it looks like a whole bunch of log entries are being made (Investigate why!), and some part of your logging system is trying to resolve "`domain names, IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, DNS resource records or services with the systemd-resolved.service(8) resolver service.`". (Read `man 8 systemd-resolved.service`.) This "name resolution" is what's taking the time.

Normal? When Linux runs on everything from Systems-On-Chip to members of the Top 50 Supercomputers, what does "Normal" mean?

Comment: "Normal" as in typical for a computer with a wifi connection running Ubuntu 16.10, I guess.